# Is there an open source realtime collaborative wiki engine?

Tags: ajax, mediawiki, real-time, collaborative

I am looking for a wiki engine that is:

- open source
- real time
- collaborative

A sort of mix between [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) and an open source version of [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/) where several users could see each other's edits in real time.

Is there such a state-of-the-art beast?

Comment: Seems like you need a gobby-plugin for mediawiki... I was looking for something like that a while ago, but never found anything.

Comment: I will also note, that this is arguably not programming related unless you're talking about writing it :)

Comment: For sure I'd prefer to find a good existing code base. It seems like a huge undertaking even though projects like pygowave may help !

Comment: FWIW, Kune website at www.kune.cc has a "wiki" based on Google Wave.  
You can setup your own node for the kune platform. It also has a simultaneous chat like etherpadlite. Not sure about the "Engine" part or "real-time" editing support though.

Comment: This may be worth a look: Howto Build a hybrid Etherpad+Docuwiki: http://canidu.com/etherwiki-howto.html

Comment: "The EtherpadLite extension adds a tag <eplite> to the MediaWiki parser and provides a method to embed Etherpad Lite pads on MediaWiki pages" See [EtherPadLite Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EtherpadLite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've answered this primarily - Google Wave or Google Docs are the big players here, though there's lots of others.

From a wiki perspective, most wiki's are written with the expectation of relatively non-granular changes (larger chunks than is typically found in collaboration). It may not be out there, and just waiting for someone like you to write it ;)

Comment: Google Wave is a big player?  Where?  :D

Comment: The question asked about open source.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't seen one, but you may be able to build off of [Sobby/Gobby](http://gobby.0x539.de/trac/) in order to create one.

Answer (score 2):

Etherpad-Lite with linkify plugin is the closest thing that you can find:

https://github.com/Pita/etherpad-lite

The linkify plugin can be installed by simply typing:

npm install ep_linkify

once you have Etherpad-Lite installed.

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to check out this experimental extension to MediaWiki: http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EtherEditor

Answer (score 1):

[EtherPad](http://etherpad.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [PmWiki](http://www.pmwiki.org/) or [PukiWiki](http://pukiwiki.sourceforge.jp/?About%20PukiWiki)?

Comment: admittedly, I did not look into PmWiki for a while, but I never saw anything like that on it ... what feature exactly do you mean? All I found was http://www.pmwiki.org/wiki/PmWiki/SimultaneousEdits and that's missing the real-time point...

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to find a similar solution for non-profit and NGO organizations and small friend groups.
Something which combines
a) one-to-group of Facebook or Google+,
b) document creation of TiddlyWiki and
c) simultaneous editing of EtherpadLite

I've found [Kune](http://kune.cc) to be among the better implemented candidates as one of it's main design goals is ease-of-use for small groups, communities and non-profits.
Zero system administration as hosting is free.
Ease of customization via Wave Gadgets.
While still in alpha stage it looks good.

Comment: [Woobius](http://woobius.com) implements a replacement for building documents via email-threads for (free for individuals and $$ for small to medium businesses)

Comment: Integration discussions for [Tiddlywiki](http://tiddlywiki.com) and [EtherPadLite](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite):  
a) https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/etherpad-open-source-discuss/r1XQ2ZEPueA
b) https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tiddlywiki/4l9TPFiix4M

Comment: FWIW, [Kune](www.kune.cc) has a "wiki" based on Google Wave. You can setup your own node for the kune platform. It also has a simultaneous chat like etherpadlite. Not sure about the "Engine" part or "real-time" editing support though.

Comment: This may be worth a look: [Howto Build a hybrid Etherpad+Docuwiki](http://canidu.com/etherwiki-howto.html)

Comment: "The EtherpadLite extension adds a tag <eplite> to the MediaWiki parser and provides a method to embed Etherpad Lite pads on MediaWiki pages" See [EtherPadLite Extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EtherpadLite)

Answer (score 0):

Atlassian's Confluence now ticks say two and half of these boxes. It has real-time collaborative editing - it's commercial though, but you can look at the source if you sign an NDA with them